# How to assign string condition to a dataframe column condition?

Tags: pandas

In a loop, I have built a string to be used as a column restriction in a panda dataframe :

```
conditions = pd.DataFrame()

for index, fold in df.iterrows():
    first_row = True
    for elem in fold['include_months']:
        if first_row: 
            condition = f"""('MonthNumber_"""+str(elem)+"' == 1)" 
            first_row = False
        else:
            condition += f""" | ('MonthNumber_"""+str(elem)+"' == 1)"
```

But I get an error with condition applied to panda column:

```
X_train = X_train[condition]

KeyError: "(X_train['MonthNumber_1'] == 1)| (X_train['MonthNumber_2'] == 1)"
```

How to fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `condition` not a string

```
condition = (X_train['MonthNumber_1'] == 1) | (X_train['MonthNumber_2'] == 1)

# since you're override your variable, it's best to make a copy
X_train = X_train[condition].copy()
```

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) if you want to use a string form:

```
condition = 'MonthNumber_1 == 1 | MonthNumber_2 == 1'
X_train = X_train.query(condition).copy()
```

Comment: Thanks but  how to make condition not a string with :this code: train_months = f"""(X_train['MonthNumber_"""+str(elem)+"'] == 1)" ?

Comment: `X_train.filter(like='MonthNumber').eq(1).any(axis=1)`.